# Data format in Cell VBA

Tags: vba, excel

*Hello,
this is my first question here and my English is not the best, so I will try to do my best to be understood.*

I got some code, where I need to insert data in format "dd/mm/yyyy" into a cell, but I don't know its format and I cannot change it (protected sheet).

```
Dim sReversalDate As String
sReversalDate = "" & Format(DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1), "dd/mm/yyyy")
sh.Range("M10").Value = sReversalDate
```

During debugging, my sReversalDate's value is "01/03/2016", but after putting it into cell, `Range("M10").Value` is "3/01/2016". Do you know how I can solve this problem? Once again - I cannot change protection of a sheet, or maybe I don't want to :) I want to check if it is possible. Thanks

One more thing. For few of cells I made trick with " ' " before date and it works. In this specific case, I cannot do it, because the cell is connected with another one which is validating it and screaming "hey, format date!" etc.

Thanks for your time and help guys :)

Comment: Please check the cell formatting once you insert the value. Depending on your system settings, entered value could be reformatted to the US settings. If you don't care whether the entered value is a text, then you can simply insert ' character before the value -> sh.Range("M10").Value = "'" & sReversalDate

Comment: I know this thing. I wrote it in my post also, but for this specific case i cannot do it, because this cell is "protected" by another cell which is validating entered data type and screaming when it is incorrect.

Also i cant get to know format of this cell, because its changed somehow and i can see "General" in Data Type. Sometimes its "Accounting" (so i guess its changed somewhere). I am done with it.. i dont have ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your initial formatting to `"mm/dd/yyyy"`, then at the end change the format of the cell to `"dd/mm/yyyy;@"`

```
Dim sReversalDate As String
sReversalDate = "" & Format(DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1), "mm/dd/yyyy")
sh.Range("M10").Value = sReversalDate
sh.Range("M10").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"
```

Comment: As i said previously, i cannot change format of cells due to fact that this worksheet is protected. I also cannot change protection of this workbook.

Comment: How are you able to populate the value in cell M10 if the sheet is protected?

Comment: IDK, i guess that properties of cells are protected, becuase whole ribbon and context menu are grey (i mean i cannot change f.e, fonts, borders etc), but i can change values of cells. Is that possible and enough clear described? Sorry for my english

Comment: Yea that makes sense, there are certain levels of protection that can be placed on a worksheet/workbook.  In this case it sounds like just the formatting for some reason.  Not sure what you're asking for is possible without knowing the password to unprotect the sheet within your VBA (see N. Pavon's answer)

Comment: I am asking is there any other way to put date (as string actually) to cell with format "dd/mm/yyyy" when it has format "mm/dd/yyyy" in my opinion and i dont know a password to protection :) I guess there isnt, and my question is a kind of these stupid :) sorry for wasting your time guys

Answer (score 0):

Write the following at the beginning of your code:

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="myPassword"
```

And this at the end:

```
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="myPassword"
```

Comment: I don't know a password of protection to this project and i don't want to destroy this workbook. Is it safe? 
I mean, is password for this workbook which i don't know will be the same after this lines of code and it will let me to change format of cell? Sorry for "newbie questions", I'm still learning

Comment: Yes, if it is protected and it does have a password, then this piece of code will leave the WB exactly as it was before running the code...

Comment: Yea, thats great idea, but i dont know a password to change protection of this workbook :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did it in other way. 
I added one line of below code:

```
sReversalDate = "'" & Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1), "mm/dd/yyyy")
.Range("M10") = sReversalDate
.Range("m10") = Right(sReversalDate, Len(sReversalDate) - 1)
```

In my case its working. I guess that formatting of a cell is bad, and months are changed with days. Anyway, probably noone of You will know the answer, without looking on this specific workbook.

Actually, none of the answers is correct, but is there possibility to give +1 if someone didn't help me, but at least he tried to?

I would like to thank everyone for your time :)

Comment: Yeah, this is more or less what I was suggesting in my comment, however keep in mind, that once you enter ' character, it automatically converts cell value to text (no matter what the content is)